# Loop over alphabet in Liquid language

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I'm creating a page with Jekyll, which has a built-in Liquid engine. I am familiar with some basic looping, but I can't get this to work.

```
{% for letter in (65..90) %}
<a href="#{{ letter }}">{{ letter }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

What I want is the output to look like

```
<a href="#A">A</a>
<a href="#B">B</a>
...
<a href="#Z">Z</a>
```

But instead I see

```
<p><a href="#65">65</a></p>

<p><a href="#66">66</a></p>

...

<p><a href="#90">90</a></p>
```

What I need is a way to convert the ASCII numbers to letters in Liquid, and I need the output to not have `<p>` tags around each thing generated by the loop.

How can I get Liquid to output something like that second code block?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, I figured it out with some help from [this](http://shopify.github.io/liquid/filters/split/).

What I really need is

```
{% assign alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" | split: "" %}
{% for letter in alphabet %}
<a href="#{{ letter }}">{{ letter }}</a>{% endfor %}
```

I've tried putting the alphabet in the for loop declaration, but it only seems to work if the alphabet is previously assigned.

The complication with `<p>` tags was because I'm doing this in a `.md` document, and the loop ends up putting a newline between each link, which gets interpreted in markdown as new paragraphs. Putting the `endfor` on the same line as the code gets rid of those newlines.